# Is there any way to set the Input required conditionally in angular?

Tags: angular, input, components, directive, required

What I'm trying to achieve is having a component/directive input required only when another input is given, for example:

```
@Input() name!:string; 
@Input({ required: name!!}) surname!:string;
```

Is this possible?

I tried to set `required: name!!` but it doesn't work as intended, the only fields I potentially have access to are static fields

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you can refer to `this` in the decorators.

Also keep in mind that `required` inputs are a compiler only feature. This information doesn't make it into the runtime bundles.

Answer (score 0):

This way that you show is not possible but if i have understood good your purpose, to achieve your goal you can use getter and setter to check when required input data is valued inside your angular child component.
For Example:

```
    private _name: string;

public get name(): string {
  return this._name;
}
@Input() public set name(value: string) {
  if (value) {
    // you can assign the value that come in input
    this._name = value;
  }
  else {
    // example: show a toast message error if !value
  }
}
```